# How does following transformations of random variables occur?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

While reading a paper related to the random mobility model, I am stuck with the following two questions. Let us start with the following equation.

$$P(L<l) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda\pi l^2),$$ where L is the random variable and $l$ is the exact value. L denotes transition length and $L = VT$ $(V,T)$ are velocity and transition-time random varible with $v,t$ as respective values.

I understand that to find pdf of transition-time $T$ find f_T(t), we have to find CDF such that:
$$P(T<t) = P(\frac{L}{V}<t) = P(L<vt) = 1-\exp(-\lambda\pi v^2t^2).$$
But since $V$ is also a random variable, how come the authors say

$$P(T<t) = P(\frac{L}{V}<t) = P(L<vt) = 1-\int_\mathcal{V}\exp(-\lambda\pi v^2t^2)dP_V(v).$$ 
where $\mathcal{V}$ is the range of velocity and $P_V(.)$ is the velocity distribution. (where does $dP_V(v)$ comes from)

**The second question is:** If the velocity is uniformly distributed on $[v_{min},v_{max}]$, I cannot understand how the pdf of transition time becomes

$$f_T(t) = \frac{g(v_{min}) - g(v_{max})}{(v_{max} - v_{min})t}, t\geq0$$ with $g(x) = xe^{-\lambda \pi t^2x^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}t}Q(\sqrt{2\pi\lambda t x})$ and $Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{u^2}{2}}$

Comment: Assuming $L$ and $V$ are independent, indeed $$P(L<Vt\mid V=v)=P(L<vt)=:h(v)$$ hence $$P(L<Vt)=E(P(L<Vt\mid V))=E(h(V))=\int_\mathbb R h(v)dP_V(v)$$ where $P_V$ denotes the distribution of $V$. This is the formula in your post.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good hint.